# Appending a single line of text to a text file using php produces a duplicate of the text on the same line

Tags: php, text, append

I am appending a single line of text to the end of a text file, but I always get two copies of the same line of text, appended on the same line, here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Store form data in .txt file</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    Enter Your Text Here:<br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];
$fp = fopen('.email_addresses_test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

and a sample image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrlpz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$data=$_POST['textdata']. "\n";
$fp = fopen('.email_addresses_test.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

"\n" in double quotes is interpreted as a line break.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks That still gives me two lines of the same text but they are now underneath each other with a blank line in between i.e blank line followed by two lines of the same text Instead of one and no blank line

Comment: Thois seems to work $data=$_POST['textdata'];
$fp = fopen('.email_addresses_test.txt', 'a');
echo "<br />";
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

Answer (score 0):

You should use [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#example-2156) with the **FILE_APPEND** flag and the **LOCK_EX** flag to prevent any other process from writing to the file at the same time. These flags are joined with the binary **OR** operator `|`.

```
$address = "email@domain";

file_put_contents(
  ".email_addresses_test.txt",
  $address . "\n",
  FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
);
```